# PHP. Как правильно отправить POSTFIELDS в cURL

Tags: php, curl

Мне нужно отправить данные POST через cURL как показано на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  $data = [
                'action' => 'order_cost',
                'address' => 'http://91.211.117.3:720'
            ];

 $query = http_build_query($data);

 $url = "https://ap4.taxi/api/TaxiAPI.php";
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvJFySHvqeKppEN9W',
                )
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            var_dump($output);
```

У меня есть такой код, но я получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал уже много вариантов. Postman отправляет POST нормально и получаю ответ.

Подскажите пожалуйста я даже не представляю как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
   'user_phone' => 38,
   ...
];

$query = http_build_query($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
```

Comment: Не работает. Ошибки теже

Comment: напишите, что вы конкретно отправляете какие данные, с моим вариантом решения

Comment: $data = [
                    'action' => 'order_cost',
                    'address' => 'http://91.211.117.3:720'
                ];

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Там указал точнее

Comment: а http_build_query где?

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос. Я его отредактировал. Там сейчас так, как у меня в коде

Comment: посмотрите моё решение и сделайте выводы

Comment: Может вы подскажете что не так? Всё идентично как у вас.